# sharing a session id/ login info between two web apps

Tags: tomcat, servlets, single-sign-on

I am running Tomcat 7 and not using any external libraries...no spring. no struts, etc.

Sorry, I am kind of a newb at this. So if a person logs in web application 1, my thought process is to usually store it in a HTTPSession.setValue(username,etc); however, I can't seem to share these sessions between two web applications.

I have read about SSO's but still really confused on how to implement it.

If someone can explain to me a simple way this can be solved, I would really love it.

Thank you

Comment: NB: You should use `HttpSession.setAttribute` instead of `HttpSession.putValue` since servlet 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Single Sign On** feature supported by **Tomcat**. Here is the [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On) which explains about that features.

Answer (score 1):

SSO only makes it so you don't have to provide credentials across multiple webapps: they still have distinct sessions and you can't communicate between them that way.

You can more easily tie non-session information together using something like a relational database or memcached.

Comment: If you just want to avoid your users from having to enter username and password more than once for your different webapps, then use SSO: that's exactly what it's there for.